# porting Quartz from IAS to JBoss AS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I am porting our code from IAS to JBoss AS.
There is strange behavior where quartz does not trigger any event at all, and no errors appear at quartz logs. I have also noticed that the Quartz tables are not populated (QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS, QRTZ_TRIGGERS etc.).

I am using JOBStoreCMT with quartz version 1.5.2.   datasource is well declared. Jobs and triggers worked well in IAS and declared within the code.

quartz properties:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = bitbandScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 15
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = bitband_pluginDS
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = bitband_pluginDSTX
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.bitband_pluginDS.jndiURL=java:bitband_pluginDS
org.quartz.dataSource.bitband_pluginDSTX.jndiURL=java:bitband_pluginDS
```

oracle-ds.xml:

```
  <xa-datasource>
             <jndi-name>bitband_pluginDS</jndi-name>
             <!-- uncomment to enable interleaving <interleaving/> -->
             <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
             <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
             <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ord-rtv063.orca.ent:1521:DB11g</xa-datasource-property>

             <xa-datasource-property name="User">RIGHTV7_VS</xa-datasource-property>
             <xa-datasource-property name="Password">RIGHTV7_VS</xa-datasource-property>
                 <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                 <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
                 <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
                 <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
             <!-- Uses the pingDatabase method to check a connection is still valid before handing it out from the pool -->
             <!--valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name-->
             <!-- Checks the Oracle error codes and messages for fatal errors -->
             <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
             <!-- Oracles XA datasource cannot reuse a connection outside a transaction once enlisted in a global transaction and vice-versa -->
             <no-tx-separate-pools/>
               <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
               <metadata>
                  <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
               </metadata>
    </xa-datasource>
```

What am I missing?
PS, When using JobStoreTX, everything works well, so I guess it is something related to the container transaction manager.

Answer (score 2):

After hanging around the problem for the last couple of days I found a solution.

Adding the property below to quartz.properties file. As simple as that.

```
 org.quartz.jobStore.dontSetAutoCommitFalse=false
```

Setting this parameter to `true` tells Quartz not to call `setAutoCommit(false)` on connections obtained from the DataSource(s). This can be helpful in a few situations, such as if you have a driver that complains if it is called when it is already off. This property defaults to false, because most drivers require that `setAutoCommit(false)` is called.

For some reason JBoss overrides the default value, so I had to add it explicitly.

The credit goes to unknown user at:
http://osdir.com/ml/java.quartz.user/2007-10/msg00123.html